# Is it possible to show changes in database from geowebcache?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Is it possible to show changes in database from geowebcache (used in conjunction with geoserver) which is showing cached data instead of reflecting changes?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/27581) on the mailing list you can notify GWC that things have changed using a GeoRSS feed.

Comment: the post says it uses by default if using with in geoserver but I can't find the changes?

Comment: The post says it's the default if you use WFS-T to make the changes and you are using the integrated GWC. I suspect you are not.